# nivo padding, bordering with box shadow

Tags: jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I integrate nivo slider on my website, I use the jquery one! not the wordpress plugin. Im having no problem when I install coz it works instantly, however when I came across of an idea that I want to make it more nice so I tried to add some few styles on the .nivoSlider class

```
padding: 8px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888 !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888 !important;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888 !important;
```

at first the padding only applies to the top and bottom of the slider as well as even using borders until I replace the

```
height: 100%;
```

to

```
max-height: 100%;
```

in the .nivoSlider class

but now the main problem here is the box shadow because, the shadow is cut out in the both sides of the slider, I mean the shadow is not showing on the left and right side of the slider (shadow is not all over the box), instead, the box shadow shows only on the top and the bottom of the slider.

I dont know what happen but Im trying to figure it out what is going on and how to fix this so Im here to ask a suggestions and ideas how to achieve the full box shadow in the slider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

fixed! I just specify the width of the slider and it works!